# Activate Javascript when click link PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a link in HTML/PHP, and on the click event, I want JavaScript/Jquery code activated/executed:

PHP/HTML:

```
echo "<a id='kodelinka' class='linknew' href=''>$kd_mrp</a>";
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#kodelinka').click(function(){        
    var value = "bbbb";
    alert("aaaaa");
    $('#kodelink').fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

How do I activate the script?

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
echo "<a id='kodelinka' class='linknew' href='javascript:;'>$kd_mrp</a>";
```

You need to prevent the anchor tag default action.Also you can do like

```
$('#kodelinka').click(function(e){        
    e.preventDefault();
```

Makesure your script is working in your page

Answer (score 0):

try to make href to go js

```
echo "<a id='kodelinka' class='linknew' href='javascript:void(0);'>$kd_mrp</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

For the PHP part, you can use either

```
<?php echo "<a id='kodelinka' class='linknew' href=''>$kd_mrp</a>"; ?>
```

or if you want to have the  in the html

```
<a id='kodelinka' class='linknew' href=''><?php echo $kd_mrp; ?></a>
```

Now for the javascript part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#kodelinka').click(function(){        
    var value = "bbbb";
    alert("aaaaa");
    $('#kodelink').fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

Incase if you didn't know, you need to have jquery for the alert function

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is 3 samples:

```
<a href="####"></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
<a href="javascript:void(null)"></a>
```

don't use href=''

Comment: It's bad... imho, href always should used.. for "Open in a new tab" properly working. Or don't use `a` if you don't need href